# how to sucessfully revoke view any definition (or any other server permissions)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, dynamic-sql

I had to grant a server permissions to an active directory group, in order to solve a LIVE Bug:

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [mycompany\webDevSeniors]
GO
```

after the permission was no longer needed I revoked it:

```
revoke VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [mycompany\webDevSeniors]
go
```

this didn't seem to revoke the permission on all databases
so I have tried it in a different way:

```
use master
go
revoke VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[dbo] to [mycompany\webDevSeniors]
go
```

still, when I use one of my procedures to check which permissions are active in a specific database, it shows the "`VIEW DEFINITION`"

```
sp_getlogindbpermissionsX @db='ATPayment',@login='MYCOMPANY\webDevSeniors'
```

[image]

as you can see on the picture below, the permission is not there at server level:

[image]

**Problem Solved:**

At the end, this is how I solved this problem:

I downloaded [the sp_foreachdb stored procedure](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) by [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)

And then I run the following command on my server:

```
sp_foreachdb @command='use ?; REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[dbo] to [mycompany\webDevSeniors]'
   --         ,@print_dbname = 1
            --,@print_command_only = 1
```

Comment: Where is sp_getlogindbpermissionsX looking,(its not a standard stored procedure)

Comment: it comes from here basically: `SELECT a.name AS Name, a.type_desc AS LoginType,b.class_desc AS ClassDesc
,b.permission_name AS ServerLevelPermission,b.state_desc AS PermissionState
FROM sys.server_principals a JOIN sys.server_permissions b
ON a.principal_id = b.grantee_principal_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because when you ran:

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [mycompany\webDevSeniors]
GO
```

`Grant` was given to that particular user. But when you tried to revoke, that was at the schema level.(2nd run). However when initially you gave the GRANT access , it was not specified at object level.Since `REVOKE` has no affect if the specified permission does not already exist.

I believe starting with creation of user and then assigning the roles accordingly can help here.

Please read [Understanding GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/) which will help you in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Revoking VIEW ANY DEFINITION and revoking VIEW DEFINITION are not the same I don't think.

- VIEW ANY DEFINITION is at the Server scope
- VIEW DEFINITION  is at the DB scope

You may want to check that first.